# How can I make the frame height dynamic to the height of the image so that the image wont get cropped?

Tags: ios, swift, image, swiftui

```
if let postImageURL = post.imageURL {
  GeometryReader{ geometry in
     let size = geometry.size
        WebImage(url: postImageURL)
             .resizable()
             .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
             .frame(width: size.width, height: size.height)
                            
             .onTapGesture {
                 isFullScreen = true
             }
           }
        .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10, style: .continuous))
        .frame(height: 200)
}
```

this is my current code, here i have set the frame height to 200 and it makes the image which has more height look crap[frame height: 200](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gjdyz.jpg)

so how can i make it dynamically adjust frame height without making the image overlap onto other image?

chatGPT suggested to remove the .frame(height: 200) line completely, but then the image every image becomes tiny.[tiny image :(](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8oeNO.png)

Comment: Share a buildable code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// You can pass URL in below method I have mentioned, Where you we canfetch Orignal Size of Images.


import SwiftUI
final class  ContentViewModel : ObservableObject {
    @Published var postURL : URL?
    
    //MARK:  Method to get Orignal Image Height And Width
    func sizeOfImageAt(url: URL) -> CGSize? {
        var size: CGSize?
        let semaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 0)
        
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
            defer { semaphore.signal() }
            guard error == nil, let data = data else {
                return
            }
            guard let source = CGImageSourceCreateWithData(data as CFData, nil) else {
                return
            }
            let propertiesOptions = [kCGImageSourceShouldCache: false] as CFDictionary
            guard let properties = CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex(source, 0, propertiesOptions) as? [CFString: Any] else {
                return
            }
            if let width = properties[kCGImagePropertyPixelWidth] as? CGFloat,
               let height = properties[kCGImagePropertyPixelHeight] as? CGFloat {
                size = CGSize(width: width, height: height)
            }
        }
        task.resume()
        
        semaphore.wait()
        return size
    }
    
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var contentVM = ContentViewModel()
    @State var height : CGFloat = 30
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            
            AsyncImage(url: contentVM.postURL) { phase in
                switch phase {
                case .empty:
                    ProgressView()
                case .success(let image):
                    image.resizable()
                        .scaledToFit()
                        .frame(height: height)
                    
                    // Method will fire when URL will change , (you can use onChange method)
                        .onReceive(self.contentVM.$postURL, perform: {  postData in
                            guard let url =  postData else { return }
                            height =     self.contentVM.sizeOfImageAt(url: url)?.height ?? 50
                            print("Height and Width ::: \(String(describing: self.contentVM.sizeOfImageAt(url: url)))")
                        })
                case .failure:
                    Image(systemName: "photo")
                @unknown default:
                    EmptyView()
                }
            }
            .onAppear(perform: {
                // Use for Explanation
                contentVM.postURL = URL(string: "https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery3/1.sm.png")
            })
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

#Preview {
    ContentView()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

first convert your image into uiImage and you can get data contentSize data using image.size property and assign that in your code